# How to change collation for view table in mysql

Tags: mysql, replace, view

- When I run this query:

> ```
> select  b.email, 
>           concat('[AAA]: Xin chao QK ', a.client_name, ' HD ',a.account_no, ' vua khoi tao')  as subject, 
>           replace( (select email_content from xxff_message where refid=1 and status='O'),'#LOAN_ID#', a.account_no) as message,  -- cp init 
>           a.loan_id
> from  interface.vw_loan_full a  
> left join interface.xxff_client b 
> on a.client_id=b.client_id 
> where 1=1 
> and a.status=100 
> and (a.loan_id, email) not in ( select loan_id, receiver from xxff_loan_message_sent where stage='INIT100_MSG_EMAIL') 
> and date(a.value_date) between DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -30 day) and  date(now());
> ```

- And I get this error:

> Err] 1270 - Illegal mix of collations (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT),
>   (utf8_unicode_ci,COERCIBLE), (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation
>   'replace'

- When I research, this cause is different utf8_unicode_ci and utf8_general_ci. But I checked all table, database are using utf8_unicode_ci .
- But view table `vw_loan_full` is utf8_general_ci. Please help me change collation of view table.
- Because I run command:

> ALTER TABLE vw_loan_full CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE
>   utf8_unicode_ci;

- And get Error:

> [Err] 1347 - 'interface.vw_loan_full' is not BASE TABLE

My result from *SHOW CREATE TABLE xxff_client*:

> CREATE TABLE `xxff_client` (   `client_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
>   `client_name` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
>   `national_id` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
>   `issue_date` date DEFAULT NULL,   `issue_place` varchar(120) COLLATE
>   utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,   `Gender` varchar(15) COLLATE
>   utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,   `dob` date DEFAULT NULL,   `phone`
>   varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,   `email`
>   varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,   `address`
>   varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,   `status`
>   varchar(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,   `creation_date`
>   date DEFAULT NULL,   `USER_ID` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
>   DEFAULT NULL,   `company_name` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
>   DEFAULT NULL,   `company_address` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
>   DEFAULT NULL,   `title` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT
>   NULL,   `dept_name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
>   `join_date` date DEFAULT NULL,   `salary_date` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
>   `remain_of_laborcontract` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,   `salary_recently`
>   varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,   `eco_userid`
>   bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,   `otp_count` tinyint(20) DEFAULT '0',
>   PRIMARY KEY (`client_id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
>   COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC

My result from *SHOW CREATE TABLE xxff_loan_message_sent*:

> CREATE TABLE `xxff_loan_message_sent` (   `refid` bigint(20) NOT NULL
>   AUTO_INCREMENT,   `loan_id` int(11) NOT NULL,   `stage` varchar(20)
>   COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,   `sent_status` varchar(6)
>   COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,   `created_by` varchar(15)
>   COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,   `created_date` date DEFAULT
>   NULL,   `receiver` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL, 
>   PRIMARY KEY (`refid`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=280 DEFAULT
>   CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC

My result from *SHOW CREATE TABLE vw_loan_full*:

> CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`%` SQL SECURITY DEFINER
>   VIEW `vw_loan_full` AS select `a`.`id` AS `loan_id`,`a`.`client_id` AS
>   `client_id`,`b`.`display_name` AS `client_name`,`b`.`account_no` AS
>   `cif_no`,`a`.`product_id` AS `product_id`,`c`.`short_name` AS
>   `product_name`,`a`.`currency_code` AS
>   `ccy_code`,`a`.`annual_nominal_interest_rate` AS
>   `rate`,`a`.`term_frequency` AS `term`,`a`.`approved_principal` AS
>   `approved_principal`,`a`.`principal_amount` AS
>   `disbursed_amount`,`a`.`principal_outstanding_derived` AS
>   `pos`,`a`.`loan_status_id` AS `status`,`a`.`submittedon_date` AS
>   `created_date`,`a`.`submittedon_userid` AS
>   `created_by`,`a`.`expected_disbursedon_date` AS
>   `value_date`,`a`.`maturedon_date` AS
>   `maturity_date`,`a`.`approvedon_date` AS
>   `approvedon_date`,`a`.`disbursedon_date` AS
>   `disbursedon_date`,`a`.`expected_maturedon_date` AS
>   `expected_maturedon_date`,`a`.`loanpurpose_cv_id` AS
>   `loan_purpose`,`a`.`account_no` AS `account_no` from
>   ((`mifostenant-default`.`m_loan` `a` left join
>   `mifostenant-default`.`m_client` `b` on((`a`.`client_id` = `b`.`id`)))
>   left join `mifostenant-default`.`m_product_loan` `c`
>   on((`a`.`product_id` = `c`.`id`)))

My result from *SHOW CREATE TABLE vw_loan_full*:

> CREATE TABLE `xxff_message` (   `refid` bigint(20) NOT NULL
>   AUTO_INCREMENT,   `msg_type` varchar(8) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
>   DEFAULT NULL,   `sms_content` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
>   DEFAULT NULL,   `email_content` varchar(2000) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
>   DEFAULT NULL,   `email_subject` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
>   DEFAULT NULL,   `status` varchar(4) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT
>   NULL,   `created_by` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
>   `created_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,   `updated_by` varchar(15)
>   COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,   `updated_date` datetime
>   DEFAULT NULL,   `stage_code` varchar(35) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
>   DEFAULT NULL,   `email_receiver` varchar(120) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
>   DEFAULT NULL,   PRIMARY KEY (`refid`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB
>   AUTO_INCREMENT=16 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
>   ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC

How I can change collation for view table in MySQL? Thanks for your helpfull !!!

MySQL 5.5 in Windows

Comment: Edit the question and add result of the following queries to the question: `SHOW CREATE TABLE xxff_client` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE xxff_loan_message_sent` and `SHOW CREATE VIEW vw_loan_full` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE xxff_message`

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I edited my question and add result, I checked collation are:

- table vw_loan_full is: utf8mb4_general_ci

but i can't change this collation. Can you help me?

Comment: Check the tables referenced in the `View` definition. one of them must be utf8_general_ci, or the one of the fields in those tables.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya thanks for your reply, I check table view vw_loan_full is utf8_general_ci. I resolved this error by add 'COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci' after 'a.account_no' (column account_no is utf8_general_ci). Thanks for your helpfull very much.